# Do babies who watch TV start speaking late?

Tags: toddler, speech, television, screen-time, growth

Our baby girl just less than two years old but she can't **speak like other** babies of the same age.
We are not worried about this, but we have a question. My baby girl understand everything, but when she wants to speak, she screams.

She started standing and walking in her 8th month, but other babies start speaking sooner than ours.

People say:

> Babies who watch TV (more than 1 hour per day) start speaking late.

Is this true?

They say:

> Because TV is a monologue and not a dialogue, baby always listens and will not try to speak, as there is no need to speak and no need to engage in conversation.

We have had a specialist look at our child, but he said that there was no problem.

We want to know whether you have had the same experience or any information about this?

Comment: TV is not good for babies, but it's impossible for us to tell you that is the issue here. You need to see your pediatrician and/or a pediatric speech pathologist.

Comment: i anm googling by that keywords but not found any useful article about this... isn't there a statistical research !!! ...?

Comment: As DA01 says, this is not an area the internet is that useful for. Have a specialist look at your child!

Comment: @RoryAlsop ok. but parents should have information about this experience..

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering (like I was), 600 days is about 19.5 months.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi Wondering, as a recap, 8 years later, do you have any insights on this issue? When did your kiddo start talking? How was her speech development from that point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am a language developmentalist and at 18 months of age I would expect an 18 month old child to have between 6 and 20 words of speech.  You have to bear in mind that development does not proceed at the same rate in all children and that 18 months is still very, very young.  As long as her understanding of spoken language is improving then that is all that matters at this point.

TV can be good for language development if it is used properly, (to stimulate, not as a babysitter which many people do), because it is further exposure to spoken language.  My recommendation at this point is not to worry too much, - I have seen children start speaking much later than this and go on to be fine.  My tips are to expose her to as much verbal interaction as possible, to create a language filled environment, to read nursery rhymes to her, (exposure to rhyme increases phonological awareness and aids language development), tell her stories, sing to her and surround her with music, - all of these are proven to have a positive impact upon language development.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say  "6 to 20 words", can you clarify if you mean some kind of "syllables with intent" or if you mean "actual words from the language(s) spoken in the home"? For example, my 19-month old says "bababa" to mean cup or bathtime or mum or tractor, and she says "tuh" to mean "behold!", or "let's go over there", etc. Is this the kind of thing you mean

Answer (score 6):

According to some research of "**American Academy of Pediatrics**", under the title of "***BABIES AND TODDLERS SHOULD LEARN FROM PLAY, NOT SCREENS***", those are the key findings:

1. Many video programs for infants and toddlers are marketed as “educational,” yet evidence does not support this.
2. Quality programs are educational for children only if they
   understand the content and context of the video. Studies
   consistently find that children over 2 typically have this
   understanding.
3. Unstructured play time is more valuable for the developing brain
   than electronic media.
4. Children learn to think creatively, problem solve, and develop
   reasoning and motor skills at early ages through unstructured,
   unplugged play.
5. Free play also teaches them how to entertain themselves.
6. Young children learn best from—and need—interaction with humans, not
   screens.
7. Parents who watch TV or videos with their child may add to the
   child’s understanding, but children learn more from live
   presentations than from televised ones.
8. When parents are watching their own programs, this is “background
   media” for their children.
9. It distracts the parent and decreases parent-child interaction.
10. Its presence may also interfere with a young child’s learning from
    play and activities.
11. Television viewing around bedtime can cause poor sleep habits and
    irregular sleep schedules, which can adversely affect mood, behavior
    and learning.
12. Young children with heavy media use are at risk for delays in
    language development once they start school, but more research is
    needed as to the reasons.

**

- **The report also recommends that parents and caregivers:**

**

1. Set media limits for their children before age 2, bearing in mind that the "**American Academy of Pediatrics**" discourages media use for this age group.
2. Have a strategy for managing electronic media if they choose to engage their children with it; Instead of screens, opt for supervised independent play for infants and young children during times that a parent cannot sit down and actively engage in play with the child. For example, have the child play
   with nesting cups on the floor nearby while a parent prepares dinner;
3. Avoid placing a television set in the child’s bedroom; and
4. Recognize that their own media use can have a negative effect on children.

Comment: TV is *not* an ideal medium for young social creatures, being social is.